# Why 2^31 is not divisible by n?

Tags: java, random, division

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29 says:

> The algorithm is slightly tricky. It rejects values that would result
>   in an uneven distribution (due to the fact that 2^31 is not divisible
>   by n). The probability of a value being rejected depends on n. The
>   worst case is n=2^30+1, for which the probability of a reject is 1/2,
>   and the expected number of iterations before the loop terminates is 2.

The algorithm:

```
int bits, val;
do {
    bits = next(31);
    val = bits % n;
} while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
```

The code tests the case where `n > 2^30` and `bits > n`. Then the most significant bit is set and turns the result in the condition into negative one.

I understand that `bits` is at most `2^31-1` => there is the 50% probability. The `bits` can be either < 2^30 or between 2^30 and 2^31

---

Anyway,

1. Why *2^31 is not divisible by n*?
2. Why is it effective only when both numbers > 2^30?

I guess some binary division magic, an overflow which breaks the uniform distribution?

Thank you!

Comment: 2^31 is 2147483648 , of all the 2147483648 values you could chose for `n`, 2147483648 can only be divided by 32 of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem caused any time you want to generate a random number in a smaller range from one in a larger range where the size of the smaller range isn't divisible by the size of the larger.

If you had a random number between 0 and 9 (inclusive) and wanted to change it to one between 0 and 3, if you just did this trivially as n%4, you'd have a 3/10 chance of getting a 0 (0, 4 or 8)%4, but a 2/10 chance of getting a 3 (3 or 7)%4.  The simplest way around this here is to just re-generate the random number if it's greater than 7.

The worst case it's talking about is when the size of the smaller range is just over half the size of the larger one, so you'll have to re-generate just over half of the time.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, sounds interesting. 

And why it tests only `n > 2^30` and not, for example `n=13`? 

Because the range (2^31) is so big that the difference in probability of each number 0..12 doesn't make difference?

Comment: @topolik: Where is a test n>2^30? I don't see such a line of code. The code tests if n is a power of to.

Comment: @DanielR The test for `n>2^30` comes from the while condition `(bits - val + (n-1) < 0)`. To be able to set the most significant bit, the n > 2^30

Comment: You misunderstand this line. The line checks if val the part of the upper segment which should not be used.

Comment: Please can you explain? I don't understand the sentence :/

Answer (score 1):

2^31 is only divisibale by a power or 2. When you check the code, this special case is treated separately without a loop. The Description is related to the rejecting-process, and there n is not a power of 2.

Answer (score 0):

#### Regarding the first question:

As I understand the sentence, it's said that an uneven distribution is caused when 2^31 is not divisible by n.

I'm sorry but I don't know for the second question.