# I think java random function has a bug.. Am I right?

Tags: java, random

I think Java random function has some bug...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

```
private static final long multiplier = 0x5DEECE66DL;
private static final long addend = 0xBL;
private static final long mask = (1L << 48) - 1;

protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
        oldseed = seed.get();
        nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}



public int nextInt(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

    if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
        return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

    int bits, val;
    do {
        bits = next(31);
        val = bits % n;
    } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
    return val;
}
```

If I think correctly, nextInt( n ) function returns uniform distribution( all integer have same probability ) in range [0, n)
**( n is positive because if it is <=0 then it will throw exception. )**

..

And I heard that the reason nextInt( n ) function doesn't simply mod the bits variable like below

```
next(31) % n
```

is because n can be smaller than next(31) and it will distort uniform distribution.
( link: [Why 2^31 is not divisible by n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929894/why-231-is-not-divisible-by-n) )

If that is the reason I think there's problem..

the original code check the condition

**bits - val + (n-1) < 0.**

but bits will always larger than val( val = bits % n and n is positive integer )
so bits - val > 0

and n - 1 >= 0 because n is positive integer.

so..

bit - val + ( n - 1 ) will be always larger than 0
so... the loop will never run twice.. Am I right??

Comment: I made poor question. sorry. The above code is not mine. It's random class reside in java sdk. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: You can fix it by editing the question. Make it as clear as you can. I'll certainly upvote it.

Comment: Insert a loop counter and have it print a message if the loop runs more than once - it does, I tried. Why? I have a suspicion but I don't know, find out yourself (hint: you're already printing stuff, be smart about what/when you print!). Notice btw that a>0,b>=0 does NOT mean that a+b>0