# Java Random nextInt(int) method

Tags: java, random

While reading the documentation of `nextInt(int)` method in `Random` class, i didn't understand what is the meaning of the following paragraph :

> The algorithm is slightly tricky. It rejects values that would result in an uneven distribution (due to the fact that 2^31 is not divisible by n). The probability of a value being rejected depends on n. The worst case is n=2^30+1, for which the probability of a reject is 1/2, and the expected number of iterations before the loop terminates is 2.

can anyone give me an example of a number that will be rejected ?

The algorithm responsible for rejecting numbers that will generate non uniform distribution is :

```
int bits, val;
do {
   bits = next(31);
   val = bits % bound;
} while (bits - val + (bound-1) < 0);
```

Source [Random class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

**Update :**

The problem will occur in the expression evaluated inside `while`, for some large values of `bits` the first operand of the expression will overflow the size of integer size, for example if we take bits=2^31-2 and bound=3, the first operand will be equal to 2^31 which overflow the maximum size of integer value (2^31-1) and it will be equal to negative value and the value of `bits` will be rejected and new value will be tested for next iteration.

Comment: Can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929894/why-231-is-not-divisible-by-n?

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question, it's still ambiguous for me.

Comment: Could you clarify in the question what is still ambiguous then? Show which parts of those answers (and those [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505355/implementation-of-java-util-random-nextint)) is troubling you?

Comment: If a random 31-bit unsigned value is generated which is between `max(n, 2^31-n)` and `2^31 -1` it is rejected and another number needs to be generated to ensure an even distribution.

Comment: @PeterLawrey see the updated question with the code responsible for rejecting, if i choose bits=2^31-41 and bound=67 it will not be rejected !

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode yes, it also depends on whether `bits` is in a region where every possible `val` is available. I was only considering powers of 2 which has simpler maths.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `val` is always available, it can take the value from 0 to 2^31-1 and for every positive `bound` value the expression evaluated inside `while` operator will never be negative.

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode The expression inside `while` will be negative when an overflow occurs and this will happen when the `bits` was too large the `bound` to get an even distribution.

Comment: e.g. if bound is `3` and bits = `2^31-2` then val will be `0` and for `2^31-1` it will be `1` but no value greater than `2^31-3` will be `2` so there is an uneven distribution.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `bits` value is returned by protected `next(31)` method which guarantees that the returned value is stored within positive 32 bits.

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode I agree that the value is never negative (it could be 0), but that doesn't mean that the expression in `while` is not negative.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Oh yes i understand, so the overflow will occur for the first operand of the expression inside `while`, thanks really so much, and im really sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: @NarutoBijuMode `bits` can be any random value from `0` to `2_147_483_647`, inclusive (so any non-negative 32-bit int). As an example, suppose we choose `bound = 1_000_000_000` and we get `bits = 2_050_000_000`. We are in the unfinished range that will bias the distribution, so we must reject the generated value and try again. The loop condition `bits - val + (bound-1)` is `2_050_000_000 - 50_000_000 + (1_000_000_000 - 1)`, which is `2_999_999_999`. As this is using 32-bit ints, that overflows to give a negative number.

Comment: @Boann Now i understand the problem, thank you really for you help.